# SVN Repository: how to verify that copied data is identical to source?

Tags: svn, copy, repository, verify

I copied a repository ONE (30 Gigabytes) into newly created repository TWO:

Old configuration:

```
 Repositories/
   ONE/
      branches
      tags/
      trunks/
```

New configuration:

```
 Repositories/
  ONE/ ...
  TWO/
       ONE/
          branches
          tags/
          trunks/
```

I used the following commands for that:

```
svnadmin dump D:/svn/ONE/ > ONE_dump

svnadmin load --parent-dir ONE D:/svn/TWO < ONE_dump
```

**Question**:
 How can I verify that data sources in the old ONE and in the copied ONE are identical?

Answer (score 1):

*The data is identical* because the [repository dump streams](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate) were designed for repository data migration. However, use the latest Subversion LTS versions to load your old dumps (something older than 1.8.x I guess). Find binary distributions for your OS at https://subversion.apache.org/packages.html.

Taking a *very paranoid view of things*, you can write a script that will prove that there are no differences in the old and new repos. Here is an example procedure:

1. Export the contents of matching revisions from both repositories into different directories:

   `svn export --revision X file:///C:\Repositories\ONE C:\OLD-REPO`

   `svn export --revision Y file:///C:\Repositories\TWO\ONE C:\NEW-REPO`

   Note that X and Y revision numbers will be different. Since you loaded the data into existing repository that already had some revisions, there will be a shift in numbers.
2. Diff the directories:

   `svn diff --old C:\OLD-REPO --new C:\NEW-REPO`

   See no output? This means that the contents are identical.
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2.

The approach above is not very convenient and I guess that it will be very time and space consuming. What about diffing textual diffs instead? Here is an alternative procedure that can be much faster and won't take that much disk space:

1. Save diff of matching revisions X and Y into two text files:

   `svn diff file:///C:\Repositories\ONE --revision X > X-rev.diff`

   `svn diff file:///C:\Repositories\TWO\ONE --revision Y > Y-rev.diff`
2. Diff these files:

   `svn diff --old X-rev.diff --new Y-rev.diff`

   See no output? That means that textual changes introduced in these revisions are identical. Therefore, the content itself should be identical, too. I am not sure how to adjust this particular instruction to work with binary content (photo, video and other non-textual content).